# How to maintain Form request value when page is refresh

Tags: c#

When post a value by form submit with request on redirect action then after refresh redirected page posted value is lost.How to maintain this request value when page is refresh.

Comment: do you have tried something by yourself? Please share your Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To persist the value(s), you could use: session variables, cookies, or query string values.